# Get the leftmost 8 bits

Tags: c#

how do I get the leftmost 8bits of array?

```
byte[] buf = new byte[] { 0x83, 0x00, 0xEE, 0x03, 0x26, 0x6D, 0x14, 0x00, 0xF1, 0x65, 0x27, 0x00, 0x19, 0x02, 0xD8, 0x0F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xDB, 0xD7, 0x0F, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2B, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0xE4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xDD, 0x0A, 0x18, 0x19, 0x00, 0x00, 0x79, 0x91, 0x87, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xA8, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x34, 0x00, 0x6A, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x0A, 0x7E, 0x42, 0x6C, 0x75, 0x65, 0x57, 0x61, 0x76, 0x65, 0x7E, 0x00, 0x09, 0x42, 0x6C, 0x61, 0x63, 0x6B, 0x44, 0x75, 0x73, 0x74 };
```

are the leftmost 8bits are `buf[0]` and the rightmost 8bits are `buf[buf.Length]`? or how do i get it? thanks.

Comment: `buf[buf.Length-1]` for the last byte

Comment: @Austin Salonen  ahahah no am just making sure :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, rightmost are

```
     buf[buf.Length-1]
```

leftmost are

```
     buf[0]
```

Comment: What about the Endians..ness?

Answer (score 1):

1 byte = 8 bits.

In the usual case, an array is a linear, contiguous block of memory. So strictly speaking, an array typically points to the first block in allocated memory space.

Leftmost (smallest index) element in array is leftmost element in memory, i.e. order is the same.

Answer: `buf[0]`

Comment: The memory layout of arrays is an implementation detail.

Comment: For those who remember FORTRAN: it stores multi dimensional array column-wise :)